# How many of each component makes up the total count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find out how many of each component make up the total count. This will be used to make a stacked bar chart.

The data looks like this.

```
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| ID | SOURCE  | MCODE | RELATED |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 1  | EMAIL   | A     | 40      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 2  | EMAIL   | A     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 3  | WEBFORM | C     | 40      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 4  |         | A     | 40      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 5  | WEBFORM | B     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 6  |         | C     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 7  |         | A     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 8  | WEBFORM | D     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 9  | EMAIL   | B     | 43      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| 10 |         | D     | 42      |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
```

What I want to know is how many of each `SOURCE` make up the count of the `MCODE` for a given `RELATED`.

For example, the results for related = 43 should be this

```
+-------+---------+-------+
| MCODE | SOURCE  | COUNT |
+-------+---------+-------+
| A     | EMAIL   | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
| A     | UNKNOWN | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
| B     | EMAIL   | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
| B     | WEBFORM | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
| C     | UNKNOWN | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
| D     | WEBFORM | 1     |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

This would be used in a stacked barchart something like this

```
+---+---------+---------+
| A | EMAIL   | UNKNOWN |
+---+---------+---------+
| B | EMAIL   | WEBFORM |
+---+---------+---------+
| C | UNKNOWN |         |
+---+---------+---------+
| D | WEBFORM |         |
+---+---------+---------+
```

I have some queries that get me the pieces that I need, but I don't know how to combine these to get the end result.

```
SELECT mcode, COUNT(mcode) as count
FROM docs
WHERE related = 43
GROUP BY mcode
ORDER By mcode ASC;

+-------+-------+
| MCODE | COUNT |
+-------+-------+
| A     | 2     |
+-------+-------+
| B     | 2     |
+-------+-------+
| C     | 1     |
+-------+-------+
| D     | 1     |
+-------+-------+
```

```
SELECT COALESCE(nullif(source,""),"unknown") AS source_document , COUNT(*) AS num
FROM docs 
WHERE related = 43
GROUP BY source_document
ORDER BY num DESC;

+-----------------+-----+
| SOURCE_DOCUMENT | NUM |
+-----------------+-----+
| webform         | 2   |
+-----------------+-----+
| unknown         | 2   |
+-----------------+-----+
| email           | 2   |
+-----------------+-----+
```

I've read some other posts that suggest that I could maybe join the table on itself to get this result? Unfortunately my sql skills are not that strong.

Here is a fiddle with the table and my queries.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bbe03/1)

Comment: The SQL Fiddle link does not work for me.

Comment: Yeah, don't know what happened to it. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MCODE, 
CASE WHEN SOURCE IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN'
     ELSE SOURCE 
END AS SOURCE, 
COUNT(RELATED) AS COUNT
FROM TEST
WHERE RELATED = 43
GROUP BY MCODE,SOURCE
ORDER BY 3
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! "ORDER BY 3" how does this work? What does 3 mean?

Comment: @SportsRacer It means 'Order by' the third column (Count). Please change it if you need to order by another column.

Comment: Ok. Cool changed it to MCODE. Thanks!